# Where should I look for a Scala framework that supports bidirectional asynchronous communication?

Tags: scala

I have a single server which can have multiple clients. Each client sends an asynchronous message to the server which immediately routes the message to a third party provider. At some point in the future, the server receives a response from the third party provider which should immediately be routed back to the sending client. I have had a look at Akka but had trouble figuring out how to route messages from the server back to clients at arbitrary points in the future. If I can be given some pointers even to the right parts of documentation I'm happy to take it from there. At the moment I am bewildered by the array of frameworks and options available.

Comment: Don't forget that you can ask specific questions about Akka here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I have had a look at Akka but had trouble figuring out how to route messages from the server back to clients at arbitrary points in the future."

When a message comes in from a client, store away the reference of the sender, so you can send to it later.

Perhaps if you elaborate on the problem you experienced we can assist?

Cheers,
√

Comment: Thank you I have received some good answers on the user forum

Answer (score 2):

[BlueEyes](https://github.com/jdegoes/blueeyes) is designed for this kind of workflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [atmosphere](http://atmosphere.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score -1):

If your clients are browsers, you can use [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) and its comet support. This [post](http://blog.fmpwizard.com/54204619) gives you one example of doing async work using Lift